# Pass multiple text in QR code

Tags: jquery, qr-code

I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/jquery-qrcode) to create a QR code.

It is working fine, but now I need to pass multiple value in the QR code.

Here is the code.

```
<script>
 $('#qrcode').qrcode({width: 340,height: 300,text: "this is a test value."});

</script>
```

Example of another data.

```
    userid: 234
name: John
```

As you can see my data is inside **text:** now I need to pass another data in that. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use \n for new line like:
$('#qrcode').qrcode({width: 340,height: 300,text: "first line \n new line"});

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you would like to use the same tag again to create QR Code with new data.

You can do it by using `$('#qrcode').empty()` on the element like

```
$('#qrcode').qrcode({width: 340,height: 300,text: "this is a test value."});
$('#qrcode').empty();
$('#qrcode').qrcode({width: 340,height: 300,text: "this is another test value."});
```

Checkout this sample I made
https://jsbin.com/kotukuqoqi/edit?html,console,output

If you need to generate a QR Code I would suggest to use google chart api like this

```
function createQrCode(text)
{
  $("#new-qrcode").html('<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl={0}"/>'.format(encodeURIComponent(text)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your data to a string -- json, for example -- and provide that as the new text value.

```
$('#qrcode').qrcode({width: 340, height: 300, text: '{"userid": 234, "name": "John"}'})
```

Then, on the receiving end, get the string and convert it back into your data object.